# Input text inside Vertical flexbox is protruding outside its container when width is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The input texts are going outside the container unnecessarily when width set to 100%

[image]

You can see that the right side of the input texts are out of their container div.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <label>
        User name / email
    </label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>
        Password
        <br>
    </label>
    <input type="password">
    <button>Login</button>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
    width: max(50%, 50vw);
    margin: auto;
}


button{
    padding: 8px 6px;
    background-color: rgb(212, 158, 120);
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: max-content;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(30, 143, 255, 0.8);
}

input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: provide a working snippet of what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include padding and borders in percentage width, otherwise they will be *added*  causing the effect you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By default, the sizing model excludes the padding and the border, so without specifying `border-box` the width of your inputs is actually 100% + (6px * 2) + (1px * 2).